# Postgres. Storage Bytea field. Toast table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

```
create table table1
(
 id          serial
  constraint pk_table1
   primary key,
 name          varchar(200) not null,
 ...
 logo          bytea
);
```

In logo i want to store images .png (32*32 pixels).
In select queries, I often do not display the data of the logo field. Would it be better to put this field in a separate table? Will queries slow down due to toast tables?

How to see in query plans toast tables?

Comment: How big is this data typically?  My concern is that 32x32 png might not be big enough to reliably trigger TOAST, in which case they would clog up the main table.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the `bytea` in a separate table; the [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) mechanism will do that for you automatically if it is big enough. If you query the TOASTed value, it will be assembled and decompressed, so there certainly is some overhead for that. However, if you don't query the `bytea`, it won't be retrieved at all. So avoid `SELECT *`, particularly if you don't need the image.